# Get responsive background-image height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Is there anyway I can get the current height of a responsive div's background-image?

I can get the image's actual size like this:

```
var img = new Image;
        img.src = $('#div').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");         
        var bgImgWidth = img.width;
        var bgImgHeight = img.height;
```

...but that doesn't tell me the size of the image after a screen resize (the background-image is set to 100%, and so scales as the window is resized)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the actual height from the div's width:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('#div').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");         
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;
var divWidth = $('#div').width();
var realImgHeight = ( bgImgHeight / bgImgWidth) * divWidth;
```

Comment: The height of the div is fixed.

Comment: So, if the height is fixed, where is the problem?

Comment: Hey Abel, do you actually work with responsive design? The height of the div has no impact on the size of the background-image's responsive size. It is simply a container to show it.

Comment: @TheBounder: @AbelPastur’s trying to help you, for free. Be polite.

Comment: answer very much improved. +1 :)